# Span TapGestureRecognizer event doens't work inside Label FormattedString on WPF

Tags: wpf, xamarin.forms

I try to create text which contains some links inside.
My sample code:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.FontSize = 14;
label.TextColor = Color.Black;
label.LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap;

FormattedString formattedString = new FormattedString();

Span span1 = new Span();
span1.Text = "first part of message (it can be long text)";
formattedString.Spans.Add(span1);

Span span2 = new Span();
span2.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
{
    Command = new Command(async () => await Launcher.OpenAsync("https://www.google.com/"))
});
span2.Text = "Link";
formattedString.Spans.Add(span2);

Span span3 = new Span();
span3.Text = "second part of text";
formattedString.Spans.Add(span3);

label.FormattedText = formattedString;
```

It works on UWP, but not on WPF.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms is frozen; approaching end of life. WPF support for XF is (was?) a "community supported Preview". [OPINION] stick with XF/UWP, or switch to Maui. Both have bugs, but Maui bugs should eventually get fixed. Beyond 2023, Maui will be strongly preferred.

Comment: You can check this [Span GestureRecognizers](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/2173) for more information.